# How to get the selected calendar date using Pikaday

Tags: javascript, pikaday

I'm new to using a pre-made calendar such as Pikaday. I just can't seem to grasp how to get the selected calendar date. The code I see online to do that just doesn't work for me so I must be doing something wrong.

I am getting the error "field is not defined".

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you so much.

````
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('id_pikaday_datepicker'),
    onSelect: function(date) {
        field.value = this.getMoment().format('Do MMMM YYYY');
console.log(field.value);
    }
});```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Readme of Pikaday on Github, field is a variable that refers to the input element that Pikaday bound to.
For example, in the following codes, `input` is the element

```html
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById('datepicker');
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: input,
    onSelect: function(date) {
        input.value = picker.toString();
    }
});
```

So just define a `field` variable, and use it in `onSelect` function, try the follow codes

```js
var field = document.getElementById('datepicker');
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('id_pikaday_datepicker'),
    onSelect: function(date) {
        // this.getMoment() is based on Moment.js
        field.value = this.getMoment()?.format('Do MMMM YYYY');
    }
});
```

If you want to use `this.getMoment().format` function, which is based on `Moment.js`, you need to import it before `Pikaday`, like

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: this.getMoment() is null

Comment: @user1292275 I've edited my answer, this.getMoment() is based on Moment.js, please the last section of my answer. Or you can refer to Pikaday's Github for more usage. The link is https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday